# How to create portable printable file from php code

Tags: php, latex, postscript

How to write a postscript file or a pdf/LaTex file from php code. I am trying to do it but not able to find a suitable way. Please guide.

Comment: `pdf/LaTeX` - awah??? Those are incredibly different kinds of output!

Answer (score 2):

I'd start php's output buffering, then just generate LaTeX code just like you'd generate HTML code. Afterwards retrieve the buffer and feed a LaTeX generator with it. Example:

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{Title}
\subsection{Subtitle}
Plain text.
\subsection{Another subtitle}
More plain text. :-P
\end{document}
<?php
  $latex = ob_get_clean();
  $file = tmpnam('/tmp');
  file_put_contents($file, $latex);
  exec('latex --output /path/to/your/result.pdf '.escapeshellarg($file));
  unlink($file);
?>
```

Note that the code above has the state of pseudo code. I just wrote stuff from memory and educated guesses, not testing anything at all. But the principle should work.